# Problem when reloading my nextjs app after modification my tailwind.config.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, eslint

i'm a junior developer and i have a problem.

My problem is: i don't very know actually what is it.
After modification a little bit my tailwind.config.ts, i have this problem, so i delete my modification and nothing changes.

When i try
`next dev`
It's build my app very well and i'm started to dev.

But after a few minutes or reloads. My index page is white, with title "404 not found".
In my chrome console, i have this :
[Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGJkM.png)

And on my PHPStorm this, but i think it's not the problem :
[PHPStorm console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiIkJ.png)

Also, i have multiple page on my app, like "wikis" or "articles". If i try to go on "https://localhost:3000/wikis". It's working, but if i go to "/" (my index), it's broken. and if i'm return on wikis, it's broken.

I search on internet why i have this problem but i don't find anything about it.

On other hand, if i try
`next start`
It's doesn't work and i have this:
[PHPStorm console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw8g2.png)

Version:

- NextJs : 14.0.4
- React: 18
- Tailwind: 3.3.0
- Typescript: 5
- ESLint: 8

Thank you everyone for your help. Enjoy. I'm here if you have some questions or something else.

Search my problem on the internet, delete my modification on tailwind.